# Bad request error 400 : consume webservice by using mime request

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httpwebrequest

For the last two weeks, i am unable to find out solution to quite simple question. Interesting things is that webservice is running well. I can call service methods by using WCF Client. It can also be accessible using SoapUI software.

The question relates about the consuming "web service through Mtom encoding". I wants to consume webservice through MIME request.

**WebService Implementation**

I have simple webservice along with AddData(int a, int b) function.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    int AddData(int i, int j);

}


public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public int AddData(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
}
```

The Binding and MessageEncoding to the webservice is BasicHttpBinding and Mtom respectively:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBasicHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
```

**Client WebService Consumtion**
At the client side/ to code to consume the webservice is as under:

```
private void webService_AddDataMIME()
    {
        string endPoint = url;
        string boundary = "MIMEBoundaryurn";
        string CRLF = "\r\n";
        string uuid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string reqUUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string attchmtUUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpWebResponse httpResp = null;

        //Create the HTTP request and set the headers
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Apache-HttpClient");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/AddData");
        string ContentType = "multipart/related ; type=\"application/xop+xml\" ;start=\"abcID\"; start-info=\"text/xml\";  boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"";
        httpRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";

        string uploadFileRequest = boundary + CRLF
              + "Content-Type:application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=\"text/xml\" " + CRLF
              + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" + CRLF
              + "Content-ID: abcID" + CRLF + CRLF
              + "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:AddData><tem:i>2</tem:i><tem:j>3</tem:j></tem:AddData></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
              + CRLF + boundary + uuid + "--" + CRLF + CRLF;

        //Convert the string to a byte array
        byte[] postDataBytes1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uploadFileRequest);

        int len = postDataBytes1.Length;
        httpRequest.ContentLength = len;

        //Post the request
        System.IO.Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postDataBytes1, 0, postDataBytes1.Length);

        string response;
        // Get response and write to console
        try
        {
            httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse respons = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)respons;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = respons.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }

        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(httpResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        httpResp.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```

**Error:** As i run the client code it returns back **'Error 400: bad request'**

The screen shot the error is:
[image]

Comment: Your request has : charset=UTF-8; type=\"text/xml\".  Do you expect the xml to have Mtom encoding?

Comment: Yes. I wants Mtom encoding.

Comment: I have removed the above two attributes. But i didn't work.

Comment: See following codeproject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632101/Mtom-Encoding-in-WCF

Comment: I have already read and implement that code in above article. But i think my question or problem do not relates along with above article theme.

Comment: i think the error arise due to some inappropriate 'httpwebrequest'.

Comment: The server has to be configured properly to accept the clients request.  I can't tell if the issue is the client end of the server end.  The webpage specifies how to configure both the client and server.  I do not think your server code matches article.  Do a search on link for "SecureHttpBinding"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182339/discussion-between-lets-do-green-and-jdweng).